# Modulo not found error

Tags: python, pywhatkit

Tengo el siguiente codigo en un entorno virtual donde estan instalado todos los paquetes a los que le he puesto import.

```
import pyautogui
import flask
import pywhatkit

pywhatkit.start_server()
```

Pero por alguna razon me sale el error de que no encuentra flask ni pywhatkit.
Aunque quando pongo pip freeze sale que estan instalados.
Y si ejecuto este codigo en la terminal de python funciona.
En conclusion me gustaria saber si alguien sabe porque quando lo tengo guardado en un archivo no detecta los modulos importados.

Comment: Tenés instalada dos o más versiones de Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema podría estar relacionado con el entorno virtual en el que estás ejecutando el archivo.
intenta activando el entorno con
`source nombre_entorno_virtual/bin/activate`

dentro del entorno virtual prueba

`pip uninstall flask`

`pip uninstall pywhatkit`

`pip install flask`

`pip install pywhatkit`